# sandwich is not providing the same covariance matrix for a poisson regression fit with an offset

Tags: r, standard-error

Poisson regression can be fit to raw data or can be fit by summarizing data and then using an offset.  The model should return the same coefficient estimates (as well as covariance estimates), regardless of the approach (full data or offset).

However it seems the `sandwich` function from `{sandwich}` returns different covariance estimates when the model uses an offset. This is particularly troubling because this means the confidence intervals and p values are effected.

Shown below is such an example.  The two covariance matrices differ when they are expected to be the same.

Is this intended behaviour?

```r
library("tidyverse")
grouped_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~treatment,        ~g,    ~y,     ~N,
  "A",      "a", 1338L, 20669L,
  "A",      "b",   36L,  1237L,
  "A",      "c", 2555L, 39438L,
  "A",      "d",  402L,  5713L,
  "B",      "a", 1281L, 19986L,
  "B",      "b",   38L,  1224L,
  "B",      "c", 2495L, 36749L,
  "B",      "d",  382L,  5646L
)
```

Re-organize data to be as if we hadn't grouped and summarized
by uncounting the number of successes (`y`)
and number of failures (`N` - `y`)

```
yes_outcomes <-grouped_data %>% 
  mutate(yy=1) %>% 
  uncount(y)

no_outcomes <-grouped_data %>% 
  mutate(yy=0) %>% 
  uncount(N-y)

# This is equivalent to the data we had before grouping
unit_data <- bind_rows(yes_outcomes, no_outcomes) %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rename(y=yy)
```

Fit one model on the ungrouped data without offset and one model on the grouped data with offset.

```
fit <- glm(y ~ treatment + g, data = unit_data, family = poisson)
offset_fit <- glm(y ~ treatment + g, data = grouped_data, family = poisson,
  offset = log(N))
```

The corresponding `sandwich` results are:

```
sandwich::sandwich(fit)
#>               (Intercept)    treatmentB            gb            gc
#> (Intercept)  0.0004689434 -2.213726e-04 -3.599604e-04 -3.621573e-04
#> treatmentB  -0.0002213726  4.385850e-04  5.526098e-06  9.843754e-06
#> gb          -0.0003599604  5.526098e-06  1.346409e-02  3.572512e-04
#> gc          -0.0003621573  9.843754e-06  3.572512e-04  5.422671e-04
#> gd          -0.0003545652 -5.331337e-06  3.572202e-04  3.571526e-04
#>                        gd
#> (Intercept) -3.545652e-04
#> treatmentB  -5.331337e-06
#> gb           3.572202e-04
#> gc           3.571526e-04
#> gd           1.544801e-03
sandwich::sandwich(offset_fit)
#>               (Intercept)    treatmentB            gb            gc
#> (Intercept)  1.672258e-04 -8.616787e-05 -1.238920e-04 -1.263405e-04
#> treatmentB  -8.616787e-05  1.742927e-04 -1.483730e-06  3.456605e-06
#> gb          -1.238920e-04 -1.483730e-06  3.554277e-04  1.246024e-04
#> gc          -1.263405e-04  3.456605e-06  1.246024e-04  2.040329e-04
#> gd          -1.237209e-04 -1.827624e-06  1.246399e-04  1.245998e-04
#>                        gd
#> (Intercept) -1.237209e-04
#> treatmentB  -1.827624e-06
#> gb           1.246399e-04
#> gc           1.245998e-04
#> gd           5.878420e-04
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: By using `family=poisson`, you're forcing the dispersion parameter to be 1. Hence the standard errors from `summary(fit)` and `summary(offset_fit)` are the same. If you estimate the dispersion from the data, you will get different standard errors. In your example, change `family=quasipoisson` in each of your fits. The standard errors will differ between `fit` and `offset_fit` wheter you estimate with "raw" or "aggregated" data. I suspect `sandwich` is trying to estimate a dispersion parameter, and the estimates differ between "raw" and "aggregated" data sets.

Comment: I suspect `family=quasipoisson` and `sandwich` are not correctly counting the degrees of freedom in `grouped_data`.

Comment: The difference is mainly due to the different treatment of the working residuals. In the unaggregated case, the outer product of the individual contributions is considered. In the aggregated case, the contributions are first summed and then the outer product is computed. Interestingly `vcov(..., adjust = TRUE)` is very close for most standard errors except for the small `g` = `b` group where the difference in degrees of freedom adjust is noticeable. I don't see an easy/obvious way to avoid this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Following some discussion on Twitter, I would say this is not obviously not the correct behaviour, though further investigation and consideration may be useful (and should probably go to CrossValidated instead of here).

If the mean model is correctly specified and the observations *are* independent, the two are estimating the same true quantity and so should be similar in large data sets.

The aggregated analysis claims that groups are independent; the individual analysis makes the stronger claim that individuals are independent.  If the mean model is misspecified, so that residuals in the same group have non-zero mean, these are meaningfully different claims.

The fact that the point estimates are identical is not as compelling as one might initially think. These are frequentist standard error estimates, so they describe the sampling distribution of the regression estimates across repeated experiments. The grouping/individual distinction potentially changes which repeated experiments we would consider.